# resultset.next() issue with com.simba.spark.jdbc42 driver

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using JDK 1.8 in my Unix server and using spark.jdbc42 to connect to Azure Databricks.

It is giving the following error message in the Unix server at `resultset.next()`:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator$Config.getAllocationManagerFactory(BaseAllocator.java:776)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig.access$801(ImmutableConfig.java:24)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig$InitShim.getAllocationManagerFactory(ImmutableConfig.java:83)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig.<init>(ImmutableConfig.java:47)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig.<init>(ImmutableConfig.java:24)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig$Builder.build(ImmutableConfig.java:485)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator.<clinit>(BaseAllocator.java:51)
         at com.simba.spark.spark.arrow.ArrowBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
         at com.simba.spark.spark.jdbc.SparkJDBC42Driver.createArrowBuffer(Unknown
 Source)
         at com.simba.spark.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.makeRowsetBuffer(Unknown
 Source)
         at com.simba.spark.hivecommon.dataengine.BackgroundFetcher.<init>(Unknown
 Source)
         at com.simba.spark.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCResultSet.moveToNextRow(Unknown
 Source)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc.common.BaseForwardResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Arrow only runs on LittleEndian systems.
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.<init>(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:64)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.<init>(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:50)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorL.<init>(PooledByteBufAllocatorL.java:49)
         at com.simba.spark.jdbc42.internal.apache.arrow.memory.NettyAllocationManager.<clinit>(NettyAllocationManager.java:33)
         ... 14 more
```

I'm using source code borrowed from here:
http://sedeks.blogspot.com/2019/05/how-to-connect-to-databricks-delta.html

The same source code is working fine in my local system with JDK 11.0.15.

Comment: what is the architecture of your server? Is it ARM based?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using non-little-endian system that doesn't support encoding data using Apache Arrow.  You may try to add `EnableArrow=0;` into the connection string, right after the `ssl=true;` part...

Comment: you are such a gem!!. that fixed the problem. Thanks a lot